# Using the PHP include in your template: Naming the file .php or .inc?

Tags: 7, theming

I'm able to load static PHP files for my theme without any problems but do I name the file as `file.php` or `file.inc`? I found out that either way works fine so which one is better?

```
<?php include ".." . base_path() . path_to_theme() . "/includes_folder/file.php"; ?>
<?php include ".." . base_path() . path_to_theme() . "/includes_folder/file.inc"; ?>
```

Remember that the files are saved in my theme folder since I'm not making a module. It's just static content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The extension ".php" is used for template files, whose extension is really ".tpl.php" files that are included from other files, such as module files, should use the ".inc" extension.

Drupal 8 uses .php (not ,tpl.php) for templates and PHP files containing classes, but still uses .inc for files loaded from modules, such as [path.inc](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!path.inc/8).

Answer (score 8):

The [Drupal 7 coding standards](https://drupal.org/coding-standards#includes) (#includes) seem to use ".inc" over ".php". If you browse the [Drupal Core](http://api.drupal.org/api/search/7/inc) you see ".inc" is used everywhere. I suggest you stick to ".inc".

Comment: I think that .php files should be reserved only for rare cases where you would like to call the file directly from a browser

Answer (score 1):

As others have answered I suggest you stick with the coding standards set out by Drupal.

Make sure to protect your files though: .inc files called directly from the browser may not be pre-process by php and therefore your source code will passed straight to the user.
This may already be done for you by Drupal at a high level, or may not be required due to webserver configuration.

Lastly consider checking inside each of your .inc files that they are *not* the entry point, devious users might cause unexpected behaviour.

Comment: What do you mean by *entry point?*

Comment: No need extra protection. Drupal .htaccess: # Protect files and directories from prying eyes.
<FilesMatch "\.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)$|^(\..*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$">
  Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>

Comment: @enchance Usualy .inc files are not called directly in the URI, they are included by a .php file. I have a check in my .inc files that stops the script if a variable (set by the calling .php file) is not set. This prevents accidental or malicious access. Having said that swan has pointed out another solution which seems better.