# Including files in template.php. failed in some cases (when using some contrib modules)

Tags: theming

In template.php, in `theme__preprocess_page` function, I am including files (as my template.php grew big, I decided to separate some operations for readability) like this:

```
 function THEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {   
// .. skipped non-related code
 include  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/" . path_to_theme() . "/template_includes/file1.inc";   

}
```

But sometimes some contrib modules complain about this. Currently I have an issue where Print module gives the following message:

```
Warning: include(): Failed opening 
'/var/www/drupal/sites/all/modules/contrib/print/template_includes/file1.inc' **for inclusion** (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') **in THEME_preprocess_page() (line 80 in** /var/www/drupal/sites/all/themes/THEME/template.php).
```

What causes paths mess?

Comment: u should simply add this(file) to your `.info` file.

Comment: that simple ? :) I have bunch of them... will try and report back here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using the PHP include in your template: Naming the file .php or .inc?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8236/using-the-php-include-in-your-template-naming-the-file-php-or-inc)

Comment: @NikhilM I don't think this is a duplicate at all to be honest :/ This one is asking about how to load files, the other is asking what they should be named...

Comment: I think there are some circumstances where path_to_theme() may not work. You don't need the DOCUMENT_ROOT part in any case. Try using `include drupal_get_path('theme', THEMENAME) .  "/template_includes/file1.inc";` instead.

Comment: Thanks  Alfred ill try your suggestion and report here. Yes i agree doc root looks unecessary.

Comment: Agree with @Chapabu about this not being a dup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the docs for [`path_to_theme()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/path_to_theme/7), there is this tidbit:

> It can point to the active theme or the module handling a themed implementation. For example, when invoked within the scope of a theming call it will depend on where the theming function is handled. If implemented from a module, it will point to the module. If implemented from the active theme, it will point to the active theme. When called outside the scope of a theming call, it will always point to the active theme.

The [Print](http://drupal.org/project/print) module invokes preprocess functions within its own preprocesss functions (look at the code), so I think that is why yours is getting called with a scope other than your theme.

You should really do your include as

```
include drupal_get_path('theme', 'YOURTHEME') . '/template_includes/file1.inc';
```

or

```
include dirname(__FILE__) . '/template_includes/file1.inc';
```

There is debate in the Drupal community which is best.

Personally, I think including code within a function is a really bad practice, and would recommend splitting out whole functions into separate file(s), and doing the include at the top.  If you go that route, then you using the second form is best.

Comment: yes, this is ultimate answer to my question+ thanks for the extra tip

Comment: reason why most of my includes are inside functions is because there are if conditions around appropriate inclusions.

Comment: and when using drupal_get_path... there is no more mess in inclusions! Ty again.